# How to create dynamic color for text?

Tags: php, html, css, colors

I have a variable which is containing a number. Now I want, if the number is positive, then its color be green, and if that number is negative, then the color of it be red. Something like this:

```
<?php
    $var1 = 5;
    $var2 = -2;
?>

<div> <?php echo $var1; ?></div>
<div> <?php echo $var2; ?></div>
```

It should be noted, in reality there is just one variable and it can be both positive and negative.

Also I want this result:

```
<div style='color:green;'>5</div>
<div style='color:red;'>-2</div>
```

Comment: did you try anything? it's as simple as checking `if((condition) >0){...}` and is an integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have a lot of numbers, why not just use a simple function? Also I would recommend using classes instead of inline styles as that is generally preferred:

```
function getNumberHtml($num) {
    $class = ($num < 0) ? 'negative' : 'positive';
    return "<div class='$class'>$num</div>";
}
echo getNumberHtml(56);
echo getNumberHtml(-5);
```

Then just add whatever you want to your CSS file. Edit your styles accordingly:

```
.negative {
    color: red;
}
.positive {
    color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For example, use an inline ternary operator in PHP. (It's like an If statement)

```
<div style='color: <?php echo ($var1 > 0 ? 'green' : 'red') ?> ;'>5</div>
<div style='color: <?php echo ($var1 > 0 ? 'green' : 'red') ?> ;'>-2</div>
```

Comment: Yes it works, but putting a condition on the way of this doesn't sound good. Because there is a lot of those numbers ..! anyway thanks +1

Comment: Well, when using a loop for a lot of numbers, you have you check each number...